# Want to use a bash for loop to grab descending months

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, syntax

We have a system that would have a cron job that deletes files up to two months ago. I'm trying to write a script to automate this, but I'm fairly new to bash scripting and was wondering if anyone would be able to help. Our files are in *%m%Y* format and I would be moving them to another directory and then deleting that directory. So for instance since we are in August (082020), I want to move all files up to June (062020) starting this year in Jan (012020).

Here is my script so far, I am basically just trying to print 012020-062020, can anyone let me know if I am on the right track?

```
#!/bin/bash

MONTHYEAR=$(date +%m%Y)
DELUPTO=$(expr $(date +%m%Y) - 20000)
CURRENTYEAR=$(date +%Y)


for (( i=$DELUPTO; i>=01 + $CURRENTYEAR; $(expr $i - 10000) ))
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: you can't do reasonable arithmetic on dates in the format MMYYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop from the format `yyyydd`, so start with

```
for (( i=202006; i>=202001; i-- )); do
     echo "${i:4:2}${i:0:4}"
done
```

It is up to you how you want to achieve this:

```
yearmonth=$(date +%Y%m)
```

or

```
MONTHYEAR=$(date +%m%Y)
yearmonth=${MONTHYEAR:2:4}${MONTHYEAR:0:2}
```

Comment: Oh shoot! This works great, I see what you're doing.. for the last expression in a bash for loop, can it only be i-- or i++?

Comment: @AlexanderD The last expression can be something else too.

Answer (score 1):

You know the month and year, extract those values and then turn it into a stamp, but you will need to insert a day value so I would make it say the 1st:

Example of converting timestamps:

```
# date -d "8/1/2020" +"%s"
1596254400

# date -d @1596254400 +"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"
Aug 01 2020 00:00:00
```

Then create a time stamp of now minutes X days:

```
date +%s -d "60 days ago"
```

Once you have common values to compare, Then compare them and if less than 60 days delete Pseudo code:

```
del_date=$(date +%s -d "60 days ago")
for each file in directory:
    #get month and day from file name here, then
    file_date=$(date -d "${fmonth}/1/${fyear}" +"%s")
    if [[ $file_date -lt $del_date ]] ;then
      echo "Older than 60 days by name"
    fi
done
```

Note: It would probably be better to delete files by checking their ages in the system using stat command opposed to reading the details of file name.

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but I love this approach as well. Honestly this would be the right way to do it but in my specific case I need to delete by the file name as these files could have been modified earlier than 2 months ago your way wouldn't work just in this case. But it does give me a better understanding of how to do something like this next time around, thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the kind consideration on your part.  I've been in the same situation as you, I wanted to delete log files older than X time frame.